# How do I get the number of hours between a Firebase TIMESTAMP and present time?

Tags: java, android, firebase, time

I am developing an app that has a feature called 'Tasks'. In tasks, the user has to complete several available tasks. Once a task has been completed, I want to disable the task for 15 hours. I am using Firebase to store the data, I am storing 'timestamp' as a child of every 'task'. The 'timestamp' gets updated every time a task is completed. Now when the user opens the 'tasks' screen in the app, I want to check for each task, if it has been 15 hours since it was last completed. I can't seem to figure out how to get the number of hours between the 'timestamp' and the present time. All I need is a hint/direction. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the data type of your timestamp in Firebase? I believe that good practice would be to use a data and time data type in UTC or a string in ISO 8601 format,for example `2018-05-14T06:59:45.238Z`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use the modern *java.time* classes for such work.

```
Duration.between(
    Instant.ofEpochMilli( firebaseMillis ) ,  // Parse count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z as a `Instant` object, a moment in UTC.
    Instant.now()                             // Capture the current moment in UTC.
)                                             // Returns a `Duration` object, a span of time unattached to the timeline.
.compareTo(                                   // The `compareTo` method implemented per the `java.lang.Comparable` interface.
    Duration.ofHours( 15 )                    // Specify your business rule of a fifteen hour limit.
)                                             // Returns an `int`, where zero means equal, over zero means greater-than, and under zero means lesser-than.
> 0                                           // Asking if our duration is over the limit of 15 hours. Returns a `boolean` primitive.
```

Notice how using these classes makes your code clear and more self-documenting.

## java.time

While I do not use Firebase, googling indicates that a Firebase `TIMESTAMP` type is a long integer count of milliseconds since the Unix epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

The modern *java.time* classes make this work quite simple.

Parse your count-of-milliseconds to an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant then = Instant.ofEpochMilli( firebaseMillis ) ;
```

Capture the current moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

By the way, to record that [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) moment, ask for the count of milliseconds from [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

```
long millisSinceEpoch = now.toEpochMilli() ;
```

Determine the elapsed time, represented as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) object, a span of time unattached to the timeline.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( then , now ) ;
```

Your goal is to compare that span of time to a target of 15 hours.

```
Duration limit = Duration.ofHours( 15 ) ;
boolean isOverLimit = ( d.compareTo( limit ) > 0 ) ;  // positive means greater-than, zero means equal, and negative means less-than.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

When you send timestamp on firebase then you send time millis.
When you have current timestamp and one timestamp of firebase. Then you can easily figure out time difference between these two.

```
long mills = firebaseTimeStamp - System.currentTimeInMillis();
int hours = millis/(1000 * 60 * 60);
int mins = (mills/(1000*60)) % 60;

String diff = hours + ":" + mins;
```

You can get current time in millis by various methods like

```
    System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: We have classes for that in the *java.time* package. No need to write the math yourself. For earlier Android before 26, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* & *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 2):

If your timestamp is stored as date and time in UTC:

```
    LocalDateTime firebaseDateTimeInUtc = LocalDateTime.of(2018, Month.FEBRUARY, 9, 16, 30);
    long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(
            firebaseDateTimeInUtc.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC),
            OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    System.out.println(hours);
```

Running just now this printed

> 2246

If your timestamp is a string in ISO 8601 format:

```
    String firebaseInstantString = "2018-02-09T16:29:46.789Z";
    long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(
            Instant.parse(firebaseInstantString), Instant.now());
```

Or if you are storing milliseconds since the epoch (this is low-level):

```
    long firebaseTimestampMillis = 1_518_193_786_789L;
    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(
            System.currentTimeMillis() - firebaseTimestampMillis);
```

In the first two snippets I am using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. You can use it on less-than-brand-new Android devices when you add ThreeTanABP to your Android project.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)